# Access Firebase node without knowing the previous one

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app with Ionic and Firebase where I create some nodes (inside others) using `push()` and the problem is that I want to be able to delete that with the app, but as I'm using `push()` I don't know the push key that it creates.

Firebase Database

[image]

practica.service.ts: Service where I delete the object with push key= -LE8mCntS-7c-aXMgpEa

```
public eliminarGrupo(grupo){
    this.afDB.database.ref('practicas/' + practica.id + '/grupos/').remove(practica.grupo);
}
```

grupo-detalle.ts: Typescript code from where I call to the service

```
eliminarGrupo(){
    this.practicaService.eliminarGrupo(this.grupo);
}
```

I didn't put the Typescript code where I get the object 'grupo' and those things because that works and it is not really necessary.
What I want to do is to delete the object 'grupo' but as I don't know the push key I don't know how to access to that object.

I hope you understood my problem, if not, ask whatever you need. I really need your help :'(

Answer (score 1):

After calling for a push you can easily get access to the ID attached to the object by

```
  this.fireDB.list(`directory`).push(data).then(res => {

        console.log(res.key); // Use this key to remove it later.

});
```